# View gets called twice when visiting on mobile in Django

Tags: django

When I visit an url on my website via mobile (no matter which browser) the mapped view is executed twice:

```
def execute_post_publisher(request):

    # Run the thread
    post_publisher_thread()

    return HttpResponse(f'New post will be created')
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Executes the post publisher
    path('tentacle/', execute_post_publisher, name='post-publisher')
]
```

How could I basically debug this to verify why?

Comment: Does it also happen when you use developer mode in your desktop browser and simulate mobile view?

Comment: @Marco nope - then it is triggered only once